# Embed Google URL Shortener stats

Tags: javascript, url-shortener, google-url-shortener

Google URL Shortener (goo.gl) provide statistics on clicked links. How to embed these statistics ?

- Components seems hardcoded in stat's page
- IFrame targeting stat's page seems to be blank
- API provide JSOn data but no sample to display charts

Any best practices ?